# Script to count two columns and echo result

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a working SQL query that I'm trying to use in a small PHP script but getting Parse error, tried many variations. Hope you can help. End result would be to have a two field form with 'Date' and 'Channel No' then giving result count of number of 'channel' rows for a given date. Sorry fairly new PHP/SQL, thanks.

```
    <?php
// Connect to MSSQL and select the database
$link = mssql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'jm_db');
mssql_select_db('jm_db');

// Select all our records from a table

$mysql_query = mssql_query ('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asterisk_cdr 
WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%'
     AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%');

echo $sql;

?>
```

I have re-done the code but getting 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource' and undefined variable.

```
<?php

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($localhost, $root, $jm_db);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$sql = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asterisk_cdr 
    WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%'
    AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%'");

    $results= array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $results[]= $result;
}

foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result['calldate'] . " " . $result['channel']; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're using the wrong variable to echo which should be `$mysql_query` and not `$sql` - You're also missing a quote. `("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asterisk_cdr 
WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%'
     AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%'")` try that, which may fix your code.

Comment: Your `$mysql_query` variable has a mis-matching number of single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Seems like OP is using the latter. Is getting a parse error, so this tells me that it's working, *somewhat*. But the missing quote and not using double quote encapsulation is the main fault.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote (Stack's syntax highlighting shows you), yet it should be replaced with an opening double quote and ending with the same. You can't use all single quotes.

I replaced the opening single quote with a double, along with a matching closing double quote.

```
$mysql_query = mssql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asterisk_cdr 
WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%'
     AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%'");
```

As a sidenote, you're echoing the wrong variable.

However, that is not how you would echo out results, but with a loop.

Something like, and replacing `Fieldname` with the one you want to use:

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($mysql_query)) {

    print $row['Fieldname'] . "\n";

}
```

or use `mssql_fetch_array()`

You can also use:

```
$results= array();
while ($result = mssql_fetch_array($mysql_query)) {
    $results[]= $result;
}

foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result['calldate'] . " " . $result['channel']; 
}
```

---

For more information on Microsoft SQL Server's function, consult:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php**

Comment: why is it allways mssql_query?

Comment: @michael Seems to be what the OP is using http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php `mssql_query()` is a valid method.

Comment: Cheers! Been confused because of $mysql and mssql_

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example with PDO

```
<?php
  try {
    $dns  = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jm_db';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';

    $options = array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    $cnx = new PDO( $dns, $user, $pass, $options );
    $select = $cnx->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM asterisk_cdr WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%' AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%'");

    $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    while( $row = $select->fetch() )
    {
      echo '<h1>', $row->count , '</h1>';
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Connect failed : ", $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
```

Comment: Ah hold on, mssql/mysql. This was a typo, I'm using MySQL so is this wrong? I know, biut I am a newbie!

Comment: I've pasted here the updated code with help from SO but still getting warnings and error with 'mssql_fetch_array'.

Comment: Down to one error. Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli().

Comment: Error I get is "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead" also "Notice: Undefined index: channel"

Comment: here is an update with PDO, replace columnName1 and columnName2 with columns that's you want to print ...

Comment: Changed the column names but getting: "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::...." Update is to display 2 columns, I just want to display the count.

Comment: paste the whole error, what is the version of php do u use? also do have PDO enabled in php ini ?

Comment: Using PHP 5.5, pdo_mysql and pdo_sqlite are enabled in wamp. Error:    Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$calldate in C:\wamp\www\jm\ And   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$channel in C:\wamp\www\jm\

Comment: sir i gave you a code to get the count and print it please delete previous code i guess you have in your code variables called $calldate and $channel and they are undefined !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mysql_query = mssql_query ('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asterisk_cdr 
    WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%'
    AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%');

    while($row=mssql_fetch_array($mysql_query))
    {
    echo $row[0];
    }
```

Comment: I'm unable to until a little later, but I did notice Aashu put while($row=mssql_fetch_array($mysql_query)), which is MsSQL? My fault from the start as I'm using MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$mysql_query = mysqli ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asterisk_cdr WHERE calldate LIKE '%2014-10-11%' AND channel LIKE '%SIP/4546975289%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo ($row["channel"]);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error showing for line:  $mysql_query = mysqli

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli(). Why is this failing?